# JS Android onClick not working

Tags: javascript, android, html

i ran into problem with JS/HTML with onClick event...

On android phone GT-I8190N (Jelly Bean Android) i cannot trigger onClick event or automatic onchange  event (like JS is not working)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Remote Control Panel
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function doThat() {
                var eSelect = document.getElementById('0');
                var radioF4 = document.getElementById('01');
                var msgboxTxt = document.getElementById('02');
                if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 1) {
                        radioF4.style = "";
                    } else {
                        radioF4.style = "visibility: hidden;";
                    }
                    if (eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
                        msgboxTxt.style = "";
                    } else {
                        msgboxTxt.style = "visibility: hidden;";
                    }
            }
            window.onload = doThat();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>
                Remote Control Panel
            </h1>
            <br>
            <br><br>
            <h3>Command:</h3>
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <select name="hh" id="0">
                <option selected="selected" value="msgbox" id="1" name="1">thing 1</option>
                <option value="altf4" id="2" name="2">thing 2</option>
                <option value="illuminati" id="3" name="3">thing 3</option>
                <option value="endilluminati" id="4" name="4">thing 4</option>
                <option value="blkmouse" id="5" name="5">thing 5</option>
                <option value="unblkmouse" id="6" name="6">thing 6</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <div>
                <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="01" name="01">
                    <input type="radio" name="01" value="enter">Send enter?
                </div>
                <div style="" id="02" name="02">
                    MessageBox Text: 
                    <input type="text" name="msgboxtext">
                </div>
                <i style="cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-refresh" onClick="doThat()" ontouchstart="doThat();"></i><a href="javascript:doThat()">eeeh</a>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send command!">
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This doesn't work too (just script in head)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var eSelect = document.getElementById('0');
            var radioF4 = document.getElementById('01');
            var msgboxTxt = document.getElementById('02');
            eSelect.onchange = function() {
                if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 1) {
                    radioF4.style = "";
                } else {
                    radioF4.style = "visibility: hidden;";
                }
                if (eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
                    msgboxTxt.style = "";
                } else {
                    msgboxTxt.style = "visibility: hidden;";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The radio button just won't appear on android but it will on my laptop.

Comment: [At me on a computer does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/r3cqzf5c)

Comment: Works for me, not on JSFiddle tho. :/

Comment: [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muh86xq9/)

Comment: Does not work. In addition, the use numbers to id - very bad practice.

Comment: That JSFiddle i posted works for me and yeah i use numbers as ID's, it has literally not much affect. Just ugly code.

Comment: May be this line ( `var eSelect = document.getElementById('0');` ) genrates problem in AndroidJB because no id named 0 and name id like a0, a1 etc. //